# This edit says Edited Tags but it does not show any changes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, edits, revisions-list

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/214741/revisions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my surprise this was my edit, so I can actually explain what happened here.  I retagged the question from [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) to [stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow), as in general [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) means "questions about the SO site" (questions usually migrated here to meta), and [stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) means "questions about stack overflow exceptions".  Some time later, these two tags were made synonyms of each other, so now the edit history appears to show no change at all.